# Run Tensorflow with googlenet

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to run the [googlenet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet) with tensorflow. Is there any multi-GPU version available that can be run with tensorflow?

Comment: Do you mean one to run inference on, or you want to train one?

Comment: train one and then validate using imagenet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can train, evaluate and fine-tune an Inception v3 model. See links there-in for pointers.
http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2016/03/train-your-own-image-classifier-with.html

Answer (score 3):

Can you also please check out: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception? (The image is from the URL.)

[image: Img from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception]